# how to replace unknown substring of line with sed

Tags: linux, sed, string

I want to replace a substring in a line, but I don't know what that substring is. I do know how the line starts though. For example, DNS1=[...to be replaced....].

I tried:

```
sed -i 's/DNS1=*/DNS1="8.8.8.8"/' /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
```

and the result was:

Before:
DNS1="10.10.2.2"

After:
DNS1="8.8.8.8""10.10.2.2"

What am I doing wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
sed -i 's/DNS1=.*/DNS1="8.8.8.8"/' /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
```

The `*` operator means "match the preceding character 0 or more times". In your example the preceding character is `=`, therefore it will match `DNS1=` and nothing more, since there are no more sequential `=` characters, and replace that portion with `DNS1="8.8.8.8"`, which generates the string `DNS1="8.8.8.8""10.10.2.2"`, just as you said.

The `.` operator means "any character" in `sed` context, which is probably what you want here. That variation will match `DNS1=` and then "any character 0 or more times" until the end of the line and then replace that with `DNS1="8.8.8.8"`.

Comment: that did the trick. I figured it was something simple like that, thanks.